# Site redirected too many times after setting let's encrypt

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, cloudflare, lets-encrypt

I have set up `www.myapp.io` which connects to a MEAN-stack application hosted by nginx. It works, now, I want to add `SSL` to it. I have followed [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04) to secure with `let's encrypt`.

However, after the configuration, `https://www.myapp.io` isn’t working: `www.myapp.io redirected you too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

The follows is `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.io`, does anyone know where is wrong?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.io www.myapp.io;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name myapp.io www.myapp.io;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.io/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:EC$
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding     "";
        proxy_set_header    Proxy               "";
        proxy_pass          https://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

(I did not put `ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;`, because I already have `ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.)

The config file before adding ssl, which worked:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myopp.io *.myopp.io;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding     "";
        proxy_set_header    Proxy               "";
        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

**PS:** The site is managed via `cloudflare`, at the moment, the `SSL` setting on `clouldflare` is `Flexible`, I don't know if I need to change it.

Comment: Yes you need to change (or drop) **Cloudflare. Flexible means** the browser connects to Cloudflare and **Cloudflare forwards to you with HTTP**, so you send back a redirect to HTTPS. The browser connects to Cloudflare with HTTPS but Cloudflare forwards to you with HTTP, so you send back another redirect to HTTPS. The browser connects again with HTTPS and gets another redirect to HTTPS, again and again, forever. Do you see any problem here?

Comment: Great... I changed `Flexible` to `Full` in ClouldFlare, `https://www.myapp.io` is reachable now... Do you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dave_thompson_085 suggested in his comment, changing `Flexible` to `Full` in Cloudflare will make `https://www.myapp.io` reachable...